# Convert from string to int in Excel for empty or blank

Tags: excel, cell, converters, string, vba

As output I have for `Range("H" & temp).Cells` :

```
234
0
   (Empty)
2
```

I want to convert it into `long` or `int`, because it's a text value. So I did

```
Range("H" & temp).Cells = CInt(Range("H" & temp).Cells)
```

It works perfectly for 234, 0 and 2 but when the cell is empty it shows me error. What should I do? I want the empty cell to be taken as 0, of course using VBA macro.

Comment: `CInt()` of an empty cell is 0.  It should work.  Could you post more of your code.  Maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

That cell isn't really empty.  It has a space or some other non-printing character in it.  Try using `Trim` before using `CInt` to get rid of the spaces.

Comment: + 1 You have hit the nail on the head. I believe the user gets a `Run Time Error 13 (type mismatch)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout In another qusetion OP post I answered earlier. I have tested with OP that cell is really a blank cell(Not space/tab/e.t.c.) using =THAT CELL/0  will give a #div/0! error, if it contains a space it will return #Value

Comment: @Larry has right, i tried it with trim but the same result. So i checked the columns format and i set it to number, now this works

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do this in formula, you can use this:
IF(IFERROR(VALUE(A1)); 0; A1)

Comment: I found in a similar situation, one way to replace a blank with zero and leave filled cells alone is to use this cell formula: =IF(IFERROR(VALUE(A1),FALSE),A1,0)

Answer (score 0):

Enter the number 1 in an unused cell and copy that cell to the clipboard. Highlight the range of cells in which you want blanks replaced by zeros. Choose Edit | Paste Special from the menu. In the Operation section of the resulting dialog box, select the Multiply option and click on OK.You have just multiplied every cell in the range by 1. Numeric cells won't change. Cells containing text data will be ignored. But any cell that was blank will now contain a zero. You could, of course, accomplish the same thing by copying a cell containing 0 to the clipboard and using Add rather than Multiply in the Paste Special dialog.

Comment: Taken from http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,1819774,00.asp used this long time ago.

Comment: but how to do it in vba excel?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub t()
Dim colNum As Long
colNum = Range("H1").Column 'please coustomize which column
For i = 1 To 4 'Please customize the row range
    Cells(i, colNum).Value = CLng(Cells(i, colNum).Value) 'blank --> 0
    Cells(i, colNum).NumberFormat = "0.00" 'also changes the numberFormat
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, a custom function, you can change variant to int or double depending on your needs

```
Function checkEmpty(value As Variant) As Variant
    If value = "" Then
        checkEmpty = 0
    Else
        checkEmpty = value
    End If
End Function
```

how to call it:

```
checkEmpty(cells(1,1).value)
```